# why does the code below cause excel to crash?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

intro and issue:

loop through columns of activesheet, if there's a title ask the user to proceed in redimensioning an array, and changing its value.

it just keeps crashing excel even after commenting out the part where the array is filled. please give me your notices and opinions on the issue.

about the code:

this is a seed of a vba script that will rearrange column from different sheets depending on the values in the array created, so each column found in activesheet represents the correct order of columns that will be saved in an array and used to fix the order of columns in a specific sheet.

I should mention that there are not many rows in the activesheet 
so arrays are 100-200 elements long of text that can be as long as 10 letters.

```
 Sub deleteColumns()
            Dim PolyArr(), PointArr(), LineArr(), autoTitle As String
            Dim crntTitle As Variant
            Dim crntRow, CrntClmn, LastRow, LastClmn As Long
            Set Wizard = ActiveSheet



  With Wizard
            LastClmn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            For CrntClmn = 1 To LastClmn
                If Len(Str(.Cells(1,CrntClmn).Value)) <> 0 Then
                    MSG1 = MsgBox("Column Index of '" & Str(.Cells(1,CrntClmn).Value) & "' . Do you wish to proceed?", vbYesNo, "Confirmation")
                        If MSG1 = vbYes Then
                            'ReDim PolyArr(Int(LastRow - 1))
                            'PolyArr = .Range("c2:c" & LastRow).Value
                        End If
                    End If
                Next CrntClmn
            End With

            'For Each CrntClmn In clmnArr


                For Each crntRow In PolyArr()
                    MsgBox (CStr(crntRow))
                Next crntRow

            'Next CrntClmn
        End Sub


**EDIT**:

I so the cause of the crash is 

    MSG1 = MsgBox("Column Index of '" & Str(.Cells(CrntClmn, 1).Value) & "' . Do you wish to proceed?", vbYesNo, "Confirmation")
                            If MSG1 = vbYes Then
                            End If

I removed the asking for user part making the code look like this:

    Sub deleteColumns()
        On Error GoTo Local_Err
        MsgBox ("hi world")
        Dim PolyArr(), autoTitle As String
        Dim crntTitle As Variant
        Dim crntRow, CrntClmn, LastRow, LastClmn As Long
        Set Wizard = ActiveSheet
        MsgBox ("hiwirld")
        With Wizard
            LastClmn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
       MsgBox ("hiwrld" & Str(LastClmn) & Str(LastRow))
            For CrntClmn = 1 To LastClmn
                MsgBox ("hidon" & Str(CrntClmn))
                If Len(.Cells(CrntClmn, 1).Value) <> 0 Then

                MsgBox ("hidonduck" & Str(CrntClmn))
                    'MSG1 = MsgBox("Column Index of '" & Str(.Cells(CrntClmn, 1).Value) & "' . Do you wish to proceed?", vbYesNo, "Confirmation")
                    'If MSG1 = vbYes Then
                        ReDim PolyArr(Int(LastRow - 1))
                        PolyArr = .Range("c2:c" & LastRow).Value
    1                'End If
                End If
            Next CrntClmn
        End With

        'For Each CrntClmn In clmnArr


            'For Each crntRow In PolyArr()
                'MsgBox (CStr(crntRow))
            'Next crntRow

        'Next CrntClmn

    Local_Exit:
        Exit Sub

    Local_Err:
        MsgBox ex & " " & Err.Description ' use ctrl-Break
        Resume Local_Exit
        Resume ' set next statement here to goto line in error
    End Sub
```

and it works now, still why cant I run the msgbox in there?

Comment: Have you run it step by step or with watches to see where it hangs up?

Comment: Use `Step Into` (`F8`) key to walk through your code one line at a time, and let us know what is the last line to execute before the crash. Also, you say "Crashes Excel". Does that mean Excel shuts down & windows reports an error, or does that mean Excel remains alive, but reports an error in your code?

Comment: yep it crashes Ms Excel and I get a message from windows explorer. now I have done the  line by line msgbox  so painfully since i need to reopen excel everytime. it crashes at :'If Len(Str(.Cells(CrntClmn, 1).Value)) <> 0 Then'

Comment: please forgive me if im not being clear or if my use of terminology is not correct

Comment: What is in the cell being checked when it crashes?

Comment: If Len(Str(activesheet.Cells(1, 1).Value)) <> 0

Comment: Sorry, I meant what is `activesheet.Cells(1, 1).Value`?

Comment: sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1).Value="FORECAST_I"

Comment: I removed all lines from the for CrntClmn = 1 to LastClmn, except for a msgbox with the value of CrntClmn it loops fine now and no crashing what's so ever. it seems that I cant have the if statment nor the vbYesNo msgbox in the loop

Comment: @Solaire Is using `CrntClmn` in the Rows field of `.Cells()` intentional? --> `If Len(Str(.Cells(CrntClmn, 1).Value)) <> 0 Then`

Shouldn't it be either `.Cells(CrntRow, 1)` or `.Cells(1, CrntClmn)`?

Comment: good notice @puzzlepiece87, I yes it should be .cells(1,CrntClmn). but its not the cause of the problem. thanks non the less.

Comment: @Solaire Is it crashing because you didn't `Dim MSG1` anywhere?

Comment: I tried to 'Dim MSG1' but it made no difference, still crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the lines where `Str(Wizard.Cells(1,CrntClmn)` was used, after removing Str() :`Wizard.Cells(1,CrntClmn`) the code ran perfectly!

Comment: if you explain the issue further more I'll accept your answer as an answer, and delete mine, Thanks for everyone's comments

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but a long comment...

Use and error handler:

```
Sub deleteColumns()
On Error GoTo Local_Err

'    <your code>

Local_Exit:
    Exit Sub

Local_Err:
    MsgBox ex & " " & Err.Description ' use ctrl-Break
    Resume Local_Exit
    Resume ' set next statement here to goto line in error
End Sub
```

Run your code to see the error. Use Ctrl-Break to go to the IDE and set the next statement to Resume.

Comment: tried that and still crashes, is this caused by an error or memory over loading?

Comment: The code doesn't run at all - just crashes? If it runs at all provide the line and error.

Comment: Although I agree that that is a good practice to get into, it is unlikely to catch the error if Excel is crashing.

Comment: yeah I'll keep the error handling lines provided by @rheitzman

Comment: The OP code doesn't crash here - may be a data dependent error.